# Inserting into SQL Server table with GUID pk from MS Access

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I'm in the process of moving our DB from an Access backend to a SQL Server backend while keeping the Access front end. One of the tables was set up with a replication ID for its PK. As an access DB, we could insert values into this table without referencing the PK field, as Access automatically generates a new GUID.

We have a function that builds a record to insert into this table that no longer works with the linked SQL Server version of the table and I'm pretty sure it must has something to do with this replcationID field. In SQL Server, it imported as data type 'uniqueidentifier'. When the function runs, it return no errors, but also inserts nothing.

I'd like to know if there is a way to get this working without changing it to a passthrough. How do I get MS Access to tell SQL Server to generate a new GUID when inserting a new record.

As a side note, the PK field is called PurchaseID and is not referenced currently in the vba (since it used to auto generate for this field)

```
Public Sub BuildReorderRecord(Market As String, MPID As String, FloorsetID As String)
Dim values As String
Dim sql As String
Dim P3ID As String
Dim Username As String
Dim dt As String
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID FROM tblAttributes WHERE MPID = """ & MPID & """")

    'Get P3ID and auditing values
    dt = Now()
    Username = Environ("USERNAME")
    P3ID = rs![ID]

    'build record values string
    values = """" & P3ID & """, """ & Market & """, """ & MPID & "', """ & FloorsetID & """"
    values = values & ", #" & dt & "#, """ & Username & """, #" & dt & "#, """ & Username & """"

    'build sql string
    sql = "INSERT INTO tblReorders (P3ID, country, mpid, floorsetID"
    sql = sql & ", CreateDate, CreatorUsername, ChangeRecord_Timestamp, ChangeRecord_Username)" & vbNewLine
    sql = sql & "VALUES(" & values & ")"

    'insert the new record
    db.Execute sql

Set db = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: I tried using newid() in the sql string, but when access runs the db.execute statement, I get an error: "Undefined function 'newid' in expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a default constraint on the table for that column in sql server like so:

```
alter table t 
  add constraint [df_t_guid]
    default newid() for [guid];
```

Or you could use a custom function in access to generate a guid like [**`stguidgen()`**](http://trigeminal.fmsinc.com/code/guids.bas)

```
insert into ... (guid...
values (stguidgen(), ...)
```

With a pass-through query, you could use `newid()` which generates a new `uniqueidentifier` in sql server.

```
insert into ... (guid...
values (newid(), ...)
```

Comment: Adding the table constraint worked well for me. Thank you for all the suggestions!