# Working with GUIDs in Acces and SQL Server database - insert GUID value into UNIQUEIDENTIFIER column

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a SQL Server database linked to a MS Access frontend.

I'm trying to store a GUID value in a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` field named `FileSorceID`. The GUID which I want to store there comes from the GUID of my current recordset (Me!GUID) which is also an `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and is created directly within the SQL server. This GUID shall be stored in my table.

But I always get an error `-2147217887 (80040e21)` when trying to do this.

So I already have a GUID which I just want to store in a different table in an `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` field. All solutions I've found were discussing about creating a new GUID within SQL Server but I already have one that I just need to store.

```vb
strCnxn = "Provider=sqloledb;" & _
"Data Source=MYSERVER;" & _
"Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE;" & _
"Integrated Security=SSPI;" 'Windows-Authentication

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strCnxn

'Recordset
sql = "AttachmentsFileStream" 'Table to add file
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open sql, strCnxn, 1, 3  '1 - adOpenKeyset, 3 - adLockOptimistic"
 
Dim GUID As Variant
GUID = Me!GUID.Value 
GUID = StringFromGUID(Me.GUID.Value)
GUID = Replace(GUID, "{guid {", "")
GUID = Replace(GUID, "}}", "")
'GUID will now hold the string "39A0483A-AE4C-44B5-94C3-00267185B81E"
'Insert into database
rs.AddNew 'FileId (also a GUID) will be automatically handled by SQL
rs!FileName = FileName
rs!FileSourceID = GUID
rs!HideFile = False

'Clean up
rs.Update
rs = Nothing
```

I've also tried to leave out the string conversion with same result.

It always stops at this line of code:

```vb
rs!FileSourceID = GUID
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting into SQL Server table with GUID pk from MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351462/inserting-into-sql-server-table-with-guid-pk-from-ms-access)

Comment: @June7 no it does not answer my question. I've edited the question to make it more clear. I already have a GUID so it does not help me to create a new one in SQL Server itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, you need to include `{`and `}`around the GUID when you want to insert it via MS Access.

Working code:

```vb
strCnxn = "Provider=sqloledb;" & _
"Data Source=MYSERVER;" & _
"Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE;" & _
"Integrated Security=SSPI;" 'Windows-Authentication

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strCnxn

'Recordset
sql = "AttachmentsFileStream" 'Table to add file
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open sql, strCnxn, 1, 3  '1 - adOpenKeyset, 3 - adLockOptimistic"
 
Dim GUID As Variant
GUID = Me.GUID.Value 'needs to be a field in the form
GUID = StringFromGUID(GUID)
GUID = Replace(GUID, "{guid {", "{")
GUID = Replace(GUID, "}}", "}")
'GUID will now hold the string like "{39A0483A-AE4C-44B5-94C3-00267185B81E}"
'Insert into database
rs.AddNew 'FileId (also a GUID) will be automatically handled by SQL
rs!FileName = FileName
rs!FileSourceID = GUID
rs!HideFile = False

'Update recordset in SQL
rs.Update
```